# How to overlay in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap, and I have an anchor tag some text that I want to overlay in a corner of another text area.  Problem is, that the bootstrap column is wasting space.  Below is what id is doing now, with highlights of the divs, and below that is how I'd like the text to flow:

#### Current

[image: Current]

```
<div id="mainWrapper" class="wrapper">
    <div class="content-main">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-10">
                    <p>Chuck Norris challenged Spain to a football match and won Chuck Norris can win a game of Connect Four in only three moves. Chuck Norris does not sleep. He waits. The Great Wall of China was originally created to keep Chuck Norris out. It failed miserably, Chuck Norris is the reason why Waldo is hiding, Chuck Norris drives an ice cream truck covered in human skulls. When Chuck Norris went to Vegas, Sinatra sang "Your Way.", Remember the Soviet Union? They decided to quit after watching a DeltaForce marathon on Satellite TV Chuck Norris counted to infinity - twice. </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-2 semi-transparent">
                    <a html="www.google.com">Spanish</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Desired Option 1 (Wrapped)

[image: Desired]

#### Desired Option 2 (Floating on Top)

[image]

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Post the code of what you've tried please.

Comment: @j08691, I'm posting what I have, but this page is brand new, so I'm open to about anything.  Just need an effcient way to transition between Spanish and English versions of a Sales Phone Agent script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bootstrap has a class meant for the close button, happens to be on the top side just like you wanted. It might be useful. Use it like this:

```
<div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-10">
    <div class="close">
        <a html="www.google.com">Spanish</a>
    </div>
    <p>Chuck Norris challenged Spain to a football match and won Chuck Norris can win a game of Connect Four in only three moves. Chuck Norris does not sleep. He waits. The Great Wall of China was originally created to keep Chuck Norris out. It failed miserably, Chuck Norris is the reason why Waldo is hiding, Chuck Norris drives an ice cream truck covered in human skulls. When Chuck Norris went to Vegas, Sinatra sang "Your Way.", Remember the Soviet Union? They decided to quit after watching a DeltaForce marathon on Satellite TV Chuck Norris counted to infinity - twice. </p>
</div>
```

You can probably add another class to it to override it.

Comment: Option 1 it is!

Comment: Glad it helped. It seems to wrap around text properly, but if you want it to overlap an image (eg inside a card), youd want something like Paul's answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Desired Option 2**

Just set the div in which you want the other div placed to `position:relative;` and then place the overlay div with `position:absolute;` and `top`, `right`, etc. where you need it.

```css
.main {
  position:relative;
  height:150px;
  background:#333;
}

.overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  height:25px;
  width:25px;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see my codepen:
[Example](http://codepen.io/KAPastor/pen/QdWeZE)

```
<html>
  <body>
<div class='container'>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10" style='background:red'>
    asfdsafsasadsfa<br>
    asfdsafsasadsfa<br>
    asfdsafsasadsfa<br>
    asfdsafsasadsfa<br>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2" style='background:yellow'>SPANISH</div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" style='background:blue'>
    asfdsafsasadsfa<br>
    asfdsafsasadsfa<br>
    asfdsafsasadsfa<br>
    asfdsafsasadsfa<br>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-md-push-9" style='background:green;position:absolute;'>SPANISH</div>
</div>

  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also please see the following: